# Array passed in props to child component returning undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using React with functional components and I'm working on a portfolio page. I wanted to create a component that displays the technologies I use.
The structure of the components would be something like this:
Skills container - divided into frontend skills, design skills etc (various components) - Skill item
I have a js file with the stack, that I would like to import to the main skill container and then pass each array to the corresponding skills component.

The problem is, when I import the array in the main skill container and pass it in props to the child component, it returns undefined.

I tried importing the same array in the child and it worked correctly, showing the data that is in the js file. But I want to have a reusable skill component, so that I don't have to create a component for each skill category.

Here's the code I have:

Js file with example skills:

```
export const stackToolsFE = [{
    tool_Name: 'React',
    tool_Img: 'https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/1126/1126012.png'
},
{
    tool_Name: 'JavaScript',
    tool_Img: 'https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/5968/5968292.png'
},];
```

Single skill item:

```
      const StackTool = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="stackToolContainer">
        <StackIcon toolName={props.tool.tool_Name} toolImgSrc={props.tool.tool_Img}/>
        <Text content={props.tool.tool_Name} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Skill category container:

```
        const TechStackTools = (props) => {
  return (
    <>
        <TextCentered variant={'s'} content={ props.toolsCategory } />
        <div className="toolsWrapper">
          {props.toolsList.map(tool => <StackTool tool={tool} />)}
        </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

Main Container

```
import { stackToolsFE } from '../../../datafiles/stack'

const TechStackSection = props => {

  const stackToolsFrontEnd = stackToolsFE;  

  return (
        <div className="techStackContainer">
            <div className="techStackTitles">
                <SectionHeader sectionTitle={'Skills'}/>
                <SectionSubheader sectionSubTitle={'Technology tools I use'} />
            </div>
            <div className="techStackToolsWrapper">
                <TechStackTools toolsCategory={'Frontend'} toolsList={stackToolsFrontEnd} />
                <TechStackTools toolsCategory={'Design'}/>
                <TechStackTools toolsCategory={'Other'}/>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

So as you can see I imported the data in the main component, tried to pass it as a new const but it didn't work neither.
But when the stack is imported in skill category and mapped, it works well.
What could be the problem?

Comment: You're rendering 3 `<TechStackTools>`, but you only pass `toolsList={stackToolsFrontEnd}` to one of them. Is the undefined coming from the other 2?

Comment: [Here's some documentation on how to create a React snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338538/1377002).

Comment: @NicholasTower no, it's coming from the first one, I wanted to try first with one component, the idea was to pass different arrays to the other <TechStackTools>

Comment: okay, so I have commented the components and left only the first one, and passed as props a different array from the same js file, and now it works correctly. So I guess the problem would be in the array itself? I will try to see what is the problem with the first array

Comment: Perhaps the import statement has a mistake. For example, not enough `../` or too many of them. Default import vs named import is another common mistake, but it looks like you correctly paired up a named import with a named export.